# Don't allow to focus out an autocomplete select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to force users to select an option from a list of items, created by jquery-ui autocomplete.
I would like to disable all the rest of the page untill they select one option, and at the same not allow the focus out of the field, since this would make the select list close. Is there a  way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a layer(a div) to cover the entire page.
Get the element that u need to enable and append it to the cover
(positioning would be needed). 
Add an out of focus handler to your element which calls focus() on that element again.

After selection is complete place the element back to it original place, and remove the cover div.

Comment: I think this solution is exactly what i was thinking about, I don't know how to put this layer though, and both the textfield and selectlist should be outside the layer

Comment: To add a covering layer you have to options. Create dynamically a div and append it to the document like:
$("body").append($("<div>",{css:{width:"100%",height:"100%","z-index":5},attr:{"id":"cover"}}))

Comment: Your code throw this exception: "DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)" 
And i think in this case my input field would be covered as well..

Comment: use prop instead of attr and hight sholud be calculated

Comment: u might want to add css position absolute as well to the div

Answer (score 0):

For native input elements, you can simply set the `disabled` attribute.

```
$('input').attr('disabled', true);
```

For jQuery UI input elements, you can set the `disabled` option.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('option', 'disabled', true);
```

So, when an option is selected:

```
// Initialize selectmenu
$('.select').selectmenu({
    // Do stuff when .select has changed
    change: function(e) {
        // Enable another input element: .datepicker
        $('.datepicker').datepicker('option', 'disabled', false);
    }
});
```